# `Get` files depending on the string input

Tags: export, import

Let's suppose I have a code like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 2;
b = 3;
Sab=*lots of calculations on a and b*
Save["S" <> ToString[a] <> "" <> ToString[b] <> ".m",{Sab}]
```

This codes construct the set `Sab` for `a=2` and `b=3` and saves a file called "S23.m". Now... I have another code like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 2;
b = 3;
Sab=*lots of calculations on a and b*
* . . . Lots of calculations on Sab . . . *
* . . . Some results . . . *
```

I would like to use `Get` in the second code to use the sets `Sab` that were previously calculated, so I wouldn't need to calculate them again, but these files depend on the inputs `a` and `b`. I tried, for example,

```
<< "S" <> ToString[a] <> "" <> ToString[a] <> "half.m"
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Just `Get[ "S" <> ToString[a] <> "" <> ToString[a] <> "half.m"]`, see linked topic for explanation and let me know if you disagree with closing

Comment: @Kuba I think the point is that `<<` reads just names, while `Got` can read a stream [this was taken from documentation]. Anyway... Should I delete this question?

Comment: Wording matters so I will just say the point is explained in the linked topic. No, it can stay as a roadsign.